# Multiple bounding boxes during Face Detection

Tags: c++, opencv

In Face detection, I tried to combine both the Frontal and Profile detectors (using Viola-Jones method). But, the system had two different bounding boxes for a single face. I used groupRectangles function which did not yield expected result of one bounded box instead of two. Kindly reply some suggestions on this issue ?

Comment: if you want to combine both rects to one: `if((profileFace && frontFace).width > 0) combinedFace = profileFace || frontFace;` will combine overlapping rectangles. Or what do you want to achieve in the end? just delete/ignore one of them (does it matter which one?)? Both ways might give problems if there are multiple people with overlapping faces really present in the image, but maybe you can handle that by comparing center of gravity of both rectangles or detect common features in both detected versions of a single face (e.g. eyes) to distinguish between multiple rects vs multiple faces

Answer (score 0):

I think Micka wanted to write bitwise operations instead of logical ones:

```
if((profileFace & frontFace).width > 0) 
    combinedFace = profileFace | frontFace;
```

Alternatively, you can merge the rectangles if their overlap is quite large, i.e.:

```
cv::Rect intersection = profileFace & frontFace;

// If the intersection is more then 80%, then use their intersection for further processing
if(std::min(intersection.area() / profileFace.area(), (intersection.area()) / frontFace.area()) > 0.8) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I always forget which of the operators is overloaded for rects. any logic how to remember it in a better way? thx

Comment: I think the way is the return value, it isn't logical (boolean) :)